# What is uninterruptible blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider this code from TIJ 4th edition

```
class SleepBlocked implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    try {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      print("InterruptedException");
    }
    print("Exiting SleepBlocked.run()");
  }
}

class IOBlocked implements Runnable {
  private InputStream in;
  public IOBlocked(InputStream is) { in = is; }
  public void run() {
    try {
      print("Waiting for read():");
      in.read();
    } catch(IOException e) {
      if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        print("Interrupted from blocked I/O");
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    print("Exiting IOBlocked.run()");
  }
}

class SynchronizedBlocked implements Runnable {
  public synchronized void f() {
    while(true) // Never releases lock
      Thread.yield();
  }
  public SynchronizedBlocked() {
    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        f(); // Lock acquired by this thread
      }
    }.start();
  }
  public void run() {
    print("Trying to call f()");
    f();
    print("Exiting SynchronizedBlocked.run()");
  }
}

public class Interrupting {
  private static ExecutorService exec =
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  static void test(Runnable r) throws InterruptedException{
    Future<?> f = exec.submit(r);
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
    print("Interrupting " + r.getClass().getName());
    f.cancel(true); // Interrupts if running
    print("Interrupt sent to " + r.getClass().getName());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test(new SleepBlocked());
    test(new IOBlocked(System.in));
    test(new SynchronizedBlocked());
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    print("Aborting with System.exit(0)");
    System.exit(0); 
  }
}
```

Here is the output

```
Interrupting SleepBlocked
InterruptedException
Exiting SleepBlocked.run()
Interrupt sent to SleepBlocked
Waiting for read():
Interrupting IOBlocked
Interrupt sent to IOBlocked
Trying to call f()
Interrupting SynchronizedBlocked
Interrupt sent to SynchronizedBlocked
Aborting with System.exit(0)
```

Here you can see that all the created threads have been interrupted at last(atleast that's what I think because no one execute its run method to last) but instead after that Bruce Eckel keeps on saying that

> you cannot interrupt a task that is trying to acquire a synchronized
>   lock or one that is trying to perform I/O.

Or does interrupt means something else here??

Also he stated that

> SleepBlock is an example of interruptible blocking, whereas IOBlocked
>   and SynchronizedBlocked are uninterruptible blocking.

What does he mean by uninterruptible blocking here? Can anyone specify the difference between two?

Comment: Why do you think all the threads have been interrupted? `print("Interrupted from blocked I/O")` never shows up in your output, for instance.

Comment: @pvg But run() method of IOBlocked has never reached to its completion, that is it is interrupted oneway or another, call it an abrupt interruption and Bruce Eckel have specified a term uninterruptible blocking here. Maybe this have any connection with it.

Comment: @abhi_awake If it never prints `"Interrupted from blocked I/O"`, it never receives an `InterruptedException`. If it never exits either, it follows immediately that it is still blocked in `in.read()`. Contrary to your assertion.

Comment: To elaborate on the other responses here, uninterruptible blocking means that a thread that has blocked on something like I/O or synchronization will not respond to interrupts. It will ignore the interrupt and continue to block the thread, and provides no response. Blocking methods should ideally implement ways for interrupts to return from the method early and notify the blocked thread, but by oversight or stupidity or whatever, it just happens that I/O cannot be interrupted. If you need interruptible locking, use a ReentrantLock.

Answer (score 1):

He is out of date, or your edition is. NIO supports interruptible I/O, via [`InterruptibleChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html), although only in the rather useless way that the channel gets closed, due to the ludicrous Linux interrupt semantics.

`java.io` and `java.net` I/O operations are not subject to interrupts, and there is nothing in your question that proves otherwise. If they were, you would have seen `"Interrupted from blocked I/O"` in the output, and you didn't. Your I/O thread is still blocked in `in.read()`.

Comment: It's technically possible to override the default interrupt behavior on InterruptibleChannel and "hack" in a signaling mechanism. I'm not actually sure if it works on Windows in fact, but it works on my Linux machine that I used to figure that out.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex When I complained, many years ago, about the `ClosedByInterruptException` semantics, the rationale advanced to me by the NIO team was that as Linux closed the FD on an interrupt, NIO had to do the same.

Comment: What I mean to say is that closing the channel is done on the Java side and that it is possible (although most likely unsafe) to avoid closing the channel on interruption if you proxy the interruption handler in AbstractInterruptibleChannel

Comment: @xTrollxDudex But not on Limux, unless the NIO team misled me.

Comment: I'd caution to say that they did. I did a small write-up about what I did (coincidentally) a few days before this. If you get the chance, would you mind confirming what I found here (yes, on Linux)? https://agenttroll.github.io/blog/2017/12/21/multi-conditionals.html

Comment: @xTrollxDudex Closing the interrupted channel is done on the Linux side. All the Java side does is mirror it. If Linux didn't behave like that, the whole `ClosedByInterrupt` fiasco wouldn't exist. Or else the NIO guys were misleading me. Im only reporting what they told me. I don't have access to Linux myself.

Comment: Ugh, I had meant interrupt, my bad. You can override the *interruption* behavior and prevent the socket from closing. Regardless, it was simply an interesting nuance that I wanted to point out. I didn't wish to contradict your answer or anything :p

Answer (score 0):

Each thread has an interrupted status that is used as a boolean flag. When someone would like to interrupt a thread, this flag is set to true. There is no precise definition of what interruption means, but it is generally used as a signal for cancellation.

A thread can get interrupted either while running and doing some work or while waiting/sleeping (in `WAITING` or a `TIMED_WAITING` state).

1. If interrupted while running, only the interrupted flag is set to true and nothing else. So logically if you want to cancel your job you should keep checking this value:

```
Callable<V> task = () -> {
    while (more work to do) {
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return null;
        // Do more work
    }
    return result;
};
```

2. If interrupted while in wait/sleep status an InterruptedException is thrown (and interrupted state is cleared, so if you check the flag within the catch block it will be false). Examples of these methods are: wait(), Thread.sleep(), BlockingQueue.get(), Semaphore.acquire() and Thread.join().

So if a method is known as uninterruptible, then you can expect that it is not going to throw an exception but will set the interrupted flag to true and continue running. You could take a look at the semaphore example with `acquire` and `acquireUninterruptibly`:

```
static class SemaphoreBlocked implements Runnable {

        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.info("Semaphore interrupted, {}", Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

static class SemaphoreBlockedUninterruptibly implements Runnable {

        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
        @Override
        public void run() {
            semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
            System.out.println("Exiting");
        }
}
```