# Java Thread interrupt only wait, join and sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

`Thread.interrupt()`:

> Interrupts this thread. Unless the current thread
>   is interrupting itself, which is always permitted, the checkAccess
>   method of this thread is invoked, which may cause a SecurityException
>   to be thrown.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the **wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int)**, methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an **I/O operation** upon an
>   InterruptibleChannel then the channel will be closed, the thread's
>   interrupt status will be set, and the thread will receive a
>   ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a **Selector** then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.
>
> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.

Lets say we have this code:

```
AtomicBoolean thread1Done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

//write in file
Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {

    try(var writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("foo.txt"))){

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            writer.write(i);
            writer.newLine();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

    thread1Done.set(true);

});

//interrupt thread1
Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {

    while(!thread1Done.get()){
        thread1.interrupt();
    }

});

thread2.start();
thread1.start();
```

`thread1` never writes anything in the file because of `thread1.interrupt()` from `thread2`.

It always ends with `java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException` at `writer.newLine();` and `foo.txt` is empty.

Is there a way to interrupt only `wait, join and sleep`, and ignore the rest?

I run my code with JDK10 on Windows10 x64.

Comment: When I run your code I assumingly get the same exception, unlike `@diginoise`. By default it seems to use an interruptible channel. However based on your question I assume you want this I/O reading part (or is that just an example for something else?) to be uninterruptible?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to not use classes from the `java.nio` package, as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47957628/11514534) indicates.

Comment: Use a `BufferedWriter` directly, not via `Files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is that to interrupt the thread only if it is block by wait, join and sleep calls and not on IO operations, you can simply check for the thread state before calling interrupt method. You can refer to the api and different states in the link follows.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

And sample code may be like the one below.

```
while ( ( thread1.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING || thread1.getState() == Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING ) && !thread1Done.get()) {
    thread1.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it stands your code runs so that `Thread 1` finishes writing 10k lines into the output text file, in other words `Thread 2` interrupts, but there are no statements in `Thread 1` which are **interruptible**. This is because (I suppose) `BufferedWriter` opens the file using **uninterruptible I/O** .

If you want your long loop in `Thread 1` to be **interruptible**, you can add the following check inside your long running loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {    //interruptible loop
        break;
    }
    writer.write(i);
    writer.newLine();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Then by delaying the interruption from `Thread 2` by say 10ms I get that only few hundred entries are being written to the file (without the delay, it gets interrupted immediately).

When I swapped `Thread 1` to use **interruptible channel**
(as is `FileChannel extends AbstractInterruptibleChannel`):

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
    FileChannel fc = null;
    try ( 
       FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("foo.txt"), 
                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    )
    {
       fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("foo.txt"), 
          StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE
       );

       for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
           fc.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("" + i).getBytes()));
           fc.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("\n").getBytes()));
           System.out.println(i);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

... I do get nicely interruptible file writing thread.

Comment: `As it stands your code runs so that Thread 1 finishes writing 10k lines into the output text file, in other words Thread 2 interrupts, but there are no statements in Thread 1 which are interruptible. This is because (I suppose) BufferedWriter opens the file using uninterruptible I/O .` You ran my code? It always get interrupted at `writer.newLine()` with `ClosedByInterruptException` and I don't want to happend that. I want to interrupt **only wait, sleep and join**.

Comment: I did run it and the whole file got written. I just tested using both JDK8 and JDK11. Are you running this on windows, linux or mac?

Comment: Windows with jdk10

Comment: That's strange. I run on Windows 10 and the whole thing just runs through. Your exception suggests that your I/O is interuptible. Mine looks like it is not.

Comment: There should be other ways around your problem, if you don't want to interrupt the writing, but waiting only. Thread 1 could signal the event of finished writing and then Thread 2 could attempt to interrupt.